# How to re-connect a local github repository I completely overwrote?

Tags: github, github-desktop

I have a Unity project that I messed up badly, so I downloaded the zip file of the latest repository I pushed to GitHub, deleted the local files, and dumped the content of that zip in place of the old directory. I thought this would be a seamless transition, but now GitHub Desktop is not recognizing these files as a git repository. I don't know why because there are github-specific files in there. I have made significant changes that I need to save. How do I reconnect this repository? Do I want to hit "Clone Again" or will that overwrite what I have locally with what is in the cloud? Again, I want to push what I have locally to the cloud.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else having this problem, here is what I did:

1. Save your local repository into a zip file someplace accessible,
   like your desktop.
2. Completely gut your local directory--delete all
   contents within the root folder. GitHub Desktop demands a clear folder to clone into.
3. In GitHub Desktop, where it says it
   can't find your repository anymore, click the button that says
   "Clone Again". This will download your cloud repository into your
   local directory--the opposite of what we wanted, but at least what
   comes next will work.
4. Delete all the cloned files that are NOT files associated with GitHub. This will prevent extraneous files from being left over when you overwrite your project files.
5. Copy all the non-GitHub-related files from the zip into the renewed directory.

This will restore the link between directories.  Now, IT IS POSSIBLE that I deleted an essential GitHub file and did not notice (since there are at least 4 of them), and simply restoring THAT file from the cloud would fix everything. If you become disconnected like I was, I recommend trying that first in case it works and saves you time. Those are the files that get overwritten by GitHub when local files are updated.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is a bit old, but I came across it and wanted to throw in what I think is a better solution:

```bash
git remote add origin <REMOTE_REPOSITORY_URL>
```

After you've done that, your repo will be linked again. Then, catch up with the changes from the server with `git fetch origin`.